# Can I close software center while installing things?

Tags: software-center

I am installing a few programs on my laptop, and the Software Center is using a lot of CPU resources. I have a few items waiting to install, and I would like to know if I can close the Software Center and have everything finish installing, or do the installations require the Software Center to be open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close the software center application while installing packages.It won't affect the package installation.Installation of packages would run on the background.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! CPU usage dropped from average of 45% to average of 3%.